# A class of solutions to $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2k\frac{dx}{dt}+(k^2+n^2)x=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

> Show that, the solution $x = \exp(-kt)(a\cos(nt)+b\sin(nt))$, for all $a$ and $b$, always satisfies the differential equation $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2k\dfrac{dx}{dt}+(k^2+n^2)x=0$.

**My try:**

$x = \exp(-kt)(a\cos(nt)+b\sin(nt))$

or, $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -k \exp(-kt) (a\cos(nt)+b\sin(nt)) + n \exp(-kt) (-a\sin(nt)+b\cos(nt))$

or, $\dfrac{dx}{dt}  = -kx + n \exp(-kt)(-a\sin(nt)+b\cos(nt))$

or, $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -k - n^2 \exp(-kt)(a\cos(nt)+b\sin(nt)) - kn \exp(-kt)(-a\sin(nt)+b\cos(nt))$

or, $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -k - n^2x - k^2x - x\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

or, $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} + x\dfrac{dx}{dt} + (n^2+k^2)x + k = 0$

What mistake am I making in this process?

Comment: I edited your question. Format stuff. See if everything is all right now.

Comment: yes, it is okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you went from your first $dx/dt$ to your second (substituting $x$ into the derivative), and then differentiated the second, you need to remember you are differentiating *with respect to $t$.*

So for example, $(-kx)' = -k\,\frac{dx}{dt}$. And as you can see, you lost the factor  $\frac{dx}{dt}$, and as a result, your second derivative is wrong.

---

Here's one way approach it, though it gets rather tedious:

Put $\color{purple}{x = \exp(-kt)\cdot (a\cos(nt)+b\sin(nt))}$, as you did.

Carefully calculate $\color{red}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$ and $\color{blue}{\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}}.$

Substitute all the above into $$\color{blue}{\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}} + 2k\cdot \color{red}{\frac {dx}{dt}} + (k^2 +n^2)\color{purple}{x}$$ Simplify and show this equals $0$.

Comment: yeah-I differentiated -kx wrt. x, but other temrs wrt. t, that's where the mistake lies. Thanks amWhy.